# How do you describe the union of variables through algebra?

Tags: probability, random-variables

There's a problem on indicator variables that involves calculating intersections for an indicator variable. I am stumped, I thought I might reach out for help on the theory.

The problem is

"Let $A,B,C$ be three events, and let $X = I_A, Y = I_B,$ and $Z = I_C$, be the associated indicator random variables. Give an algebraic expression, in the spirit of $X*Y$ is the indicator random variable of the event $A \cap C$, involving $X,Y$ and $Z$ for the indicator random variable of the following events."

The event $A^{c} \cap B \cap C$

This seems pretty clear, it is the probability of not $A$ and $B$ and $C$ and I thought it might be $(1 - X) * Y * Z$

The part that really stumps is the last part. It says at most two of the events $A,B,C$ occurred. My thinking is that in set notation this would be $(A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C) \cap (B \cup C)$ but then when I think about indicator random variables, unions stop making sense.

How do you describe the union of variables through algebra?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: Your solution works for exactly two, but at most two includes just one or none.

Answer (score 2):

Use
$$I_{A\cup B}=I_A+I_B-I_AI_B=1-(1-I_A)(1-I_B).$$

Then
$$I_{A\cup B\cup C}=I_{A\cup B}+I_C-I_{A\cup B}I_C
=I_A+I_B+I_C-I_AI_B-I_AI_C-I_BI_C+I_AI_BI_C.$$
Note the resemblance to inclusion/exclusion.
Alternatively,
$$I_{A\cup B\cup C}=1-(1-I_{A\cup B})(1-I_C)
=1-(1-I_A)(1-I_B)(1-I_C).$$

But the event "at most two of $A$, $B$, $C$ occur" is $(A\cap B\cap C)^c$
with indicator function $1-I_{A\cap B\cap C}$,